# Search For Characters in a String

Tags: php, string, function

```
$str1 = "HEADINGLEY";
$str2 = "HDNGLY";
```

how can i seach string 1 to see if it contains all the characters from string 2 in the order they exist in string 2 and return a true or false value ?

Any help appreciated :D

if this helps, this is the code i have todate..

```
echo preg_match('/.*H.*D.*N.*G.*L.*Y.*/', $str1, $matches);
```

returns 0

Comment: What do the "/" characters in the regular expression do? I have never used PHP but "H.*D.*N.*G.*L.*Y" is a correct matching regex for what you want.

Comment: "/" used as begin-end symbols of expression in string

Comment: I've updated my answer with a conversion from $str2 to a pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I'd use `preg_match`

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

...and turning `$str2` into a regular expression using `str_split` to get an array and `implode` to turn it back into a string with `".*"` as glue between characters.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php
http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Upate -- I should have suggested str_split instead of explode, and here is the code that will get you a regular expression from `$str2`

```
$str2pat = "/.*" . implode(".*", str_split($str2)) . ".*/";
```

Comment: Exactly, it would be the fastest and prettiest way to check that.

Comment: yep, this was much faster, especially when ran against the 488meg file of strings i have !!!
Thank you to everyone :D

Answer (score 0):

You could use some regular expression match like `.*H.*D.*N.*G.*L.*Y.*` and `preg_match`.

Should be easy enough to add the `.*` in the second string.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that your string is array and after that use `array_diff` function.

http://hu2.php.net/array_diff

```
$str1 = "HEADINGLEY";
$str2 = "HDNGLY";

$arr1 = str_split($str1, 1);
$arr2 = str_split($str2, 1);

$arr2_uniques = array_diff($arr2, $arr1);

return array() === $arr2_uniques;
```

Comment: Order matters in the question - it's not as simple as using `array_diff`

Comment: just add result comparison with empty array, 3 min and I will provide code example

Comment: Used part of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279202/php-convert-string-to-array

Answer (score 0):

This code is in C# as I don't know PHP but should be easy to understand.

```
        int index1 = 0, index2 = 0;
        while (index1 < str1.Length && index2 < str2.Length)
        {
            if (str1[index1] == str2[index2]) index2++;
            index1++;
        }
        if (index2 == str2.Length) return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this snippet will do it:

```
var contains = true;

for (var i=0; i < str2.length; i++) 
{
    var char = str2.charAt(i);
    var indexOfChar = str1.indexOf(char);

    if (indexOfChar < 0)
    {
        contains = false;
    }

        str1 = str1.substr(indexOfChar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pre_match function, like that:

```
$split_str2 = str_split($str2);
// Create pattern from str2
$pattern = "/" . implode(".*", $split_str2) . "/";
// Find
$result = preg_match($pattern, $str1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use some regular expression but be weary of strings that contained regex specific characters. This solution does it programmatically.

```
function contains_all_characters($str1, $str2) 
{
   $i1 = strlen($str1) - 1;
   $i2 = strlen($str2) - 1;

   while ($i2 >= 0)
   {
      if ($i1 == -1) return false;
      if ($str1[$i1--] == $str2[$i2]) $i2--;
   }

   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$str = 'HEADINGLEY';
if (preg_match('/[^H]*H[^D]*D[^N]*N[^G]*G[^L]*L[^Y]*Y/', $str, $m))
   var_dump($m[0]);
```

**Update:** Even better is to build regex like this and then use it:

```
$str = 'HEADINGLEY';
$pattern = 'HDNGLY';

$regex = '#' . preg_replace('#(.)#', '[^$1]*$1', $pattern) . '#';
if (preg_match($regex, $str, $m))
   var_dump($m[0]);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
string(10) "HEADINGLEY"
```