# Convert a php string to array php from a "JSONish" format

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any way besides for [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to convert a php string that looks like: `"[2,0,[]]"` into an array?

My array output should be like:

```
array(2,0,array())
```

And `"[2,0,[1,2,3,4]]"`  this sting should be:

```
array(2,0,array(1,2,3,4))
```

I do not want to use  [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)  because it just seems like to much code for a very simple task. in javascript it is a one liner:

```
JSON.parse('[2,0,[1,2,3,4]]');
```

Comment: How is the result supposed to look like?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: And what is wrong with explode? In case the character to explode on is used elsewhere, you might use a regex.

Comment: Expected result is array(2,0,array())?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP convert string to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279202/php-convert-string-to-array)

Comment: @SagarNaliyapara, No, here is a JSON string actually, so different solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your input looks like a JSON string, which can be converted with [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function :

```
json_decode("[2,0,[]]", true); 

/*
Array (
    0 => 2,
    1 => 0,
    2 => 
    Array (
    ),
)
*/
```

Comment: thank you. i did not think that would work because it is not valid json.

Comment: i should have known that would work because i did that in JavaScript.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard oh i thought all json needed to start with {  } , ok my bad

Answer (score 0):

As specified by Tareq Mahmood `json_decode` would work but in case you want to do it from scratch:

```
<?php
$string = "[2,0,[1,2,3,4,]]";

$i = 0;
$array = array();
$handlerCount = 0;
$arrayTmp = array();
$countArr2=0;
while(isset($string[$i])){
        switch($string[$i]){
                case ",":
                        break;
                case "[":
                        $handlerCount++;
                        break;
                case "]":
                        $handlerCount--;
                        break;
                default:
                        if($handlerCount == 1){
                                $array[$i] = (int)$string[$i];
                        }else{
                                $arrayTmp[$countArr2] = (int)$string[$i];
                                $countArr2++;
                        }

        }
        $i++;
}
array_push($array,$arrayTmp);

var_dump($array);
?>
```

[Proof of concept]

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [3]=>
  int(0)
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(2)
    [2]=>
    int(3)
    [3]=>
    int(4)
  }
}
```